# R readr::read_csv taking forever to read one vector

Tags: r, csv, vector, readr

Here is the link to my csv file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5j06r7cclg60c12/text_detected.csv?dl=0

When I used my go-to supposedly lightening fast function as usual:

```
readr::read_csv("text_detected.csv")
```

It Took Forever.

Could anyone kindly suggest a better alternative and pinpoint the problem? Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `data.table`:

`data.table::fread("text_detected.csv")`